# ibm liberty server. wlp-javaee8-20.0.0.6. How to register callback handler for ws-security

Tags: websphere-liberty

The section 3.b on [Securing a web service by using a WS-Security policy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_wssec_securing.html) requires placing the custom callback handler under the following path:

```
build.image/wlp/usr/extension/lib/SampleCbh.jar
build.image/wlp/usr/extension/lib/features/wsseccbh-1.0.mf
```

The following is the content of the wlp-javaee8-20.0.0.6\wlp\usr\ path.

```
.settings\
servers\
shared\
.project
```

There is no 'extension/lib' directory under that path.
Where the SampleCbh.jar and wsseccbh-1.0.mf files should be placed?

Answer (score 0):

As the workaround I've registered the JAR under the wlp/lib/ and the MF under the wlp/lib/features/ paths.
I am not sure if it is the recommended way to register custom user features as they contains the vendor features.